# Asp.net C# using Youtube API comment on Youtube video

Tags: asp.net, youtube, youtube-api

Why my comment is not post in youtube through asp.net c#, I use a dev key and Youtube Api.Codes run smoothly. But the comment is not posted. Am I missing any step to comment?

```js
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("YouTubeDemo", " ", "Dev key"); 
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
Comment c = new Comment(); 
c.Content = "Test Comment"; 
Video newVideo = new Video(); 
//gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments;
//newVideo.VideoId = "R9dfJaOK4xM"; 
newVideo.VideoId = "gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/4wlYIN-lpEo/comments";; 
request.AddComment(newVideo, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to provide Cliend ID?
All the operations that need write permissions need to pass Client ID and Developer Key.

> Note that your authentication request
>   must specify a clientID and
>   developerKey, both of which are
>   specified in the sample code, to
>   retrieve private feeds, upload videos,
>   or submit API requests for write
>   operations. Please visit
>   http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard
>   to obtain a developer key and client
>   ID.

You can get more info from this [page](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Authentication).

Comment: i dont know abou cliend id.And clint Id is not require message publish when i get dev key.Whats a problem @ Vijaya.........Thanks

Comment: Note that you no longer need to provide a Client ID with YouTube API requests.

Comment: Above message display when i got Dev key